# jQuery select only tags with background-color property?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to use jQuery to select all the tags in the DOM and only affect the ones with a background-color property set? I want to eventually add different color schemes and that is just a matter of the background colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
var hasBackground = $("*").filter(function() {
    return !!this.style.backgroundColor;
});
```

...after which, `hasBackground` would be a set of elements on which the `background-color` style had been *directly* set (e.g., not via a style rule).

But I would think the best way to apply "themes" to a site would be to swap out CSS stylesheets, rather than rules on individual elements, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jsbin.com/evilit/1">
<link id="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jsbin.com/ireted/1">
<script>
(function() {

  setInterval(swapStyles, 1000);

  function swapStyles() {
    var style = $("#style");
    if (style[0].href.indexOf("ireted") === -1) {
      style[0].href = "http://jsbin.com/ireted/1";
    }
    else {
      style[0].href = "http://jsbin.com/uhoqob/1";
    }
  }

})();
</script>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/esoler/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/esoler/1/edit)

Where `http://jsbin.com/evilit/1` is:

```
body {
  font-size: 26pt;
}
```

and `http://jsbin.com/ireted/1` is:

```
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and `http://jsbin.com/uhoqob/1` is:

```
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Note that in the example, there are *two* stylesheets being loaded. The first defines the font size, the second (which we swap out every second) defines the background color.

Comment: One of my problems is, if I put my style into a .css file, and apply it, the entire website breaks. Like nothing shows but the solid backgroudn-overlay color. I've tried media="Screen" and all that, but it just won't work in a .CSS file. It's really puzzling.

Comment: @WASasquatch: Sounds like you may be overriding styles that are functional rather than decorative. Make sure the stylesheet you're swapping out only defines the themeable things.

Comment: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/ That is what happens if I use a stylesheet with my style. background-images break and style is not shown correctly. Compared to http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/index_raw.html

Comment: ... Uhh nevermind. Just wow. :P You know what I wasn't seeing. :P Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to do absolute paths when putting the style in a CSS file.